# Kotlin - print function expressions

Tags: kotlin

In C# I can represent a function expression like so

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

The string representation of the function expression looks like this

> (a, b) => (a + b)

In Kotlin I can represent a function expression like so

```
val add = { a: Int, b: Int -> a + b }
```

The string representation of the function expression looks like this

> (kotlin.Int, kotlin.Int) -> kotlin.Int

Is there a way that Kotlin can represent the function expression more aligned to C#, showing the input parameters and the function body?

Comment: If you want to write your own function to print a signature with parameters, you can use Kotlin reflection to do so.  Have you tried this yet?

Comment: @JaysonMinard I had a hunch you could do it with reflection but I’ve not enough experience with the reflection API to know how to do so

Comment: @JaysonMinard The problem is the body rather than parameters.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeah, no luck on printing the body like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val add = { a: Int, b: Int -> a + b }
```

is equivalent to

```
Func<int, int, int> add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

not to `Expression<...>`. And if you print that, you'll see something like `System.Func<int, int, int>`, like in Kotlin.

I don't think Kotlin has a type like `Expression` in the standard library, or that you can implement it without language support. Its reflection API is richer than Java's (see [`KFunction`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-function/index.html)) but doesn't let you access the body. You could do it with byte code manipulation libraries, but it would be *a lot* of work.